# Simulating Correlated Continuous Variable Given 2 Existing Binary Variables

Tags: correlation, simulation, beta-distribution, copula

I am looking to draw samples from a Beta distribution (let's say α = 3 and β = 2) conditional on *two* existing binary variables in a correlated manner.

Let's call the variable distributed as a Beta as `varC`, whilst the two existing binary variables are `varA` and `varB`.

- `varA` and `varC` are correlated 0.3
- `varB` and `varC` are correlated 0.2
- `varA` and `varB` are correlated 0.1

I'm not really sure if a / which copula would be appropriate here, or if there is another method that folks would recommend.

```r
library(MASS)

set.seed(100)

# Existing Data generated using a Gaussian Copula method for StackExchange example.

varA_marginal = 0.4 # proportion of varA observations that are True
varB_marginal = 0.5 # proportion of varB observations that are True

n <- 10000 # existing obs
dims <- 2 # number of observed variables

sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1), nrow = dims) # lets say our existing 
    # variables an observed cor = ~0.1, 
    # need input cor of 0.2 to get that here.

corr_normal = mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0,dims), Sigma = sigma, empirical = T) 
      # generating correlated normal samples

corr_quantiles = pnorm(corr_normal) # computing quantiles

existing_data = data.frame(varA = qbinom(corr_quantiles[, 1], size = 1,  
    prob = varA_marginal), varB = qbinom(corr_quantiles[, 2], size = 1, 
    prob = varB_marginal))

cor(existing_data$varA, existing_data$varB) # effective correlation ~0.1
```

Comment: By "existing" binary variables do you mean you want to generate the Beta variate *conditional* on a sample of those variables?  Or do you want to generate all three variables jointly?

Comment: Specifying the correlation between a beta and a binary variable will be harder using a Gaussian copula than specifying the parameters of the copula. Are you determined to have those correlations, or just those parameters of the Gaussian copula? // Just because you specify that `varA_marginal = 0.4` does not mean that the observed/simulated variable $A$ will be $40\%$ `True`. It could be $39\%$ `True` or $41\%$ `True` (or even $25\%$ or $0\%$ `True`, depending on your sample size and how unlucky you get).

Comment: @whuber - apologies my question wasnt clear. The Beta should be _conditional_ on the samples of varA and varB

Comment: When specifying a correlation of $0.2$ on the normal variates, the corresponding correlation between the quantile transforms is no longer $0.2$.